# How to show only one result from each type in a mysql array php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a php array to display information from a database. I want to be able to show items like this **ex. Space Quest (3)** The '(3)' represents the number of times found in the database. Right now it is pulling the info and listing the results as many times as shows in the database like this **ex. Space Quest Space Quest Space Quest** which link to the individual stories. Here is my code:

```
<?php
  $type = $_POST['Type'];

  $result = mysqli_query($cxn, "SELECT * 
                                  FROM Stories 
                                 WHERE Type = '$type'");

if($result < 0) {
  echo "<center><b>No stories are posted for this category yet.</b></center>";
} else {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $title = $row['Title']; 
    $result2 = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    echo "<FORM ACTION ='browse.php' METHOD ='POST'>
            <INPUT TYPE = 'Submit' name='cool2' id='cool2' VALUE = '$title'>";
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color = '#0000ff''>(" . $result2 . ")";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
  }
} ?>
```

This code shows all the items that come from type, but I want to organize the results to show the items only once but then the number of stories in each category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run the following query instead

```
"SELECT Title,count(*) as cnt FROM Stories WHERE Type = '$type' group by Title"
```

then you'll only get distinct titles, and the cnt column will contain the number of times it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're using

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

This is going to iterate over all of the rows in the result. Instead, if you just want the first one, do

```
$row = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
$occurrences = mysqli_num_rows($result);
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understand correctly, what you want is a grouping function. For example:

```
select id, title, count( * ) from stories where type = 'ANYTHING' group by id, title
```

It's that?

Comment: In most schema's you probably wouldn't want the ID in there like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not answer to your question, but it is useful information to know anyway:

Your SQL query is vunerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection) attacks. This is because you are directly inserting user input (the POST parameter) into your SQL query string. For string values, you should use a string escape function, which ensures the string is inserted safely into the query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Stories WHERE Type = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($type) . "'";
```

It is also a good idea to escape any values that you output to your HTML code.  This helps prevent [Cross-Site Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks.  Use the [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function to do this:

```
echo "<INPUT TYPE = 'Submit' name='cool2' id='cool2' VALUE = '" . htmlspecialchars($title) . "'>";
```